# Searchkick: how to save records in ElasticSearch in different indices based on record timestamp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a Rails Model with Searchkick.

I want my model instances to be saved in ElasticSearch in different indices based on the month creation of the instance.
Lets say I have the following instances in my Model:

- A created the 03/25/2021
- B created the 03/28/2021
- C created the 04/01/2021

Instead of having one ES index (which is the default behavior for Searchkick), how can I store when my instances are created:

- A & B in ES index labeled: *model_2021_03*
- C in ES index labeled: *model_2021_04*

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, there are two main steps:

1. Create Multiple Index(indices)
2. Store the document in one of those index.

Idea here is making the index as "Write_Index" in which you want to put the document and mark others as "Read_Index".

So you can start with:

```
1. Creating an Index Template.

    PUT /_index_template/model_template

    {
       "index_patterns": [
            "model*"
        ],
        "priority": 1,
        "template": {
            "aliases": {
                "model":{}
            },
        "mappings": {
          "dynamic":"strict",
          "_source":
          {"enabled": false},
          "properties": {
           //your filed mappings here
          }
        },
        "settings": {
        "index": {
          "number_of_shards": 1,  
          "number_of_replicas": 3
        }
      }
      }
    }

 2.Create an index for a particular month,which will follow the model template(in step 1) with an naming strategy in your code 

  PUT model_YYYY_MM
```

Ex: lets say, you create two index model_2021_03, model_2021_04, now you want to store the documents in one of them,

> Idea here is to mark the index, that you want to store the document in
> as "Write_Index" and all other as "Read_Index", so when you store the
> document using alias name("model") here, it will get stored in write
> index by default.

```
3. Making the index as write index and others as read
POST /_aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {"add": 
    {"index": "model_2021_04",
    "alias": "model",
    "is_write_index": true}
    },
     {"add": 
    {"index": "model_2021_03",
    "alias": "model",
    "is_write_index": false}
    }
  ]
}

4.Finally putting documents in index using alias name

PUT /model/_doc/1
{
//your data here
}
```

Comment: @sandino, Welcome, do let me know what happens, I am also learning:)